# Is there a difference between "assistant manager" and "manager assistant"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Would a switch of the word 'assistant' and 'manager' cause differences in a universal corporate context?

In my opinion, *assistant manager* is just a rank below a *manager*. This seems to apply to *manager assistant*.

Comment: see [Dwight Schrute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_Schrute) and [Gareth Keenan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gareth_Keenan) for examples of manager's assistants, who are not assistant managers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that assistant manager is a level below a manager, whereas a manager assistant is an assistant to the manager, and not necessarily just below in level to the manager. Manager assistant seems to be more close to secretary in rank.

Comment: So the assistant manager is a just a sort of "deputy manager" (if you will) and the manager assistant is reminiscent of a secretary.

One is a sub-manager and one is a sidekick?

Comment: @Rant Well, that's another way of looking at it. People in different organisations might have different official designations for the same generic post. I'm sure that 'sidekick' wouldn't be an official designation in any sane organisation though! ;)

Comment: As a conclusion, I think Rant's comment have make Ambar answer more brighter. Marked as answer and +1 for Rant.

Comment: it's worth noting that "the office" made extensive use of this wording as a joke in the UK with Gareth always saying he was "assistant manager" with David Brent always slightly correcting "assistant TO the manager" quietly behind him.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between an assistant manager and an assistant to a manager, these two terms serve the same purpose.

Comment: [I'm sure Dwight would disagree.](http://theoffice.wikia.com/wiki/Assistant_Regional_Manager)